# Ignore SSL Validation for Portable Class Library Targeting Windows 8.1 using a Soap client

Tags: ssl, windows-8.1, soap-client, portable-class-library

I CANNOT use the following namespaces:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
```

Using a service reference generated soapclient.

How can I ignore ssl validation?

Comment: Use an anonymous cipher like Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) or Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) or Anonymous Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (AECDH). Both cipher suite omit the server certificate, so there's no validation performed.

Comment: Is there a detailed blog or tutorial on how to go about doing that? Using asp.net on IIS 7, do you create the test cert with specific properties?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in your scenario, but you can override the *ServerCertificateValidationCallback* of the global *ServicePointManager* of the application :

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
        Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        };
```

*ServicePointManager* is in the *System.Net* namespace, so it should be ok.

Comment: ServicePointManager is not available when targeting windows store applications or windows phone applications.

Comment: Maybe because Microsoft doesn't want horribly insecure apps in the store? If you want allow man-in-the-middle so badly, why not just use HTTP?